# tinymce install to symfony 2 directory (no access to ssh)

Tags: symfony, path, tinymce-4

I want to install tinymce to my symfony project what is the proper way of doing this? I am having errors like

mysite.com/app_dev.php/js/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css failed GET

I just inserted my tinymce folder to my public/bundles/mybundles/js/tinymce